# Liberty login error in trace log for wim model message - ClassCastException Entity and LoginAccount

Tags: security, websphere, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have configured Websphere Liberty to use LDAP to authenticate user. I have enabled security trace -

> com.ibm.ws.security.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.*=all:com.ibm.oauth.*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.security.oauth20.*=all:com.ibm.ws.transport.http.*=all:org.apache.http.client.*=all

I have following feature list enabled in WebSphere `Liberty v17.0.0.3`,
`webProfile-7.0`, `javaMail-1.5`, `ldapRegistry-3.0` and `localConnector-1.0`.

However, secure content is failing with error **HTTP 401 (Unauthenticated)**. 
In trace file, I can see that LDAP is able to return logged in user data. But WebSphere Liberty is failing with error -

> com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.model.Entity incompatible with  com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.model.LoginAccount
>                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.model.Entity incompatible with com.ibm.wsspi.security.wim.model.LoginAccount
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.util.SecurityNameBridge.getUserSecurityName(SecurityNameBridge.java:203)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry.getUserSecurityName(WIMUserRegistry.java:316)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.authentication.internal.jaas.modules.ServerCommonLoginModule.getSecurityName(ServerCommonLoginModule.java:104)

Please help guide if this error is due to any configuration problem.

Comment: Do you have a userSecurityNameMapping set in your server.xml?

Comment: I am using ldapRegistry tag with setting as <ldapRegistry baseDN="ou=xxxxxxx,o=xxxxx" host="xxxx.xxxx.xxx" id="xxxxx" ldapType="IBM Tivoli Directory Server" port="636" realm="xxx" recursiveSearch="true" sslEnabled="true" sslRef="sslrepo1">
     <idsFilters userFilter="(&amp;(mail=%v)(objectClass=ePerson))" userIdMap="*:mail"/>
    </ldapRegistry>   -> This has idsFilters defined to map incoming user id with ldap attribute

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved after correcting configuration of registry used. I was using LDAP registry and had mentioned LDAP server type as Tivoli. This was causing the problem in Subject class being returned from LDAP not matching expected class in Liberty. Once I changed LDAP service type to Custom, this error got resolved. Below is the tag for LDAP registry I used in server.xml

```
<ldapRegistry baseDN="ou=xxxxxxxx,o=xxxxxx" host="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" id="xxxxxxxxxxx" ldapType="Custom" port="636" realm="xx" recursiveSearch="true" sslEnabled="true" sslRef="sslrepo1">
    <customFilters userFilter="(&amp;(mail=%v)(objectclass=ePerson))" userIdMap="*:mail"/>
</ldapRegistry>
```